# ¿Cómo detectar un clic fuera de un elemento?

Tags: javascript

Tengo algunos botones: menu y buscador, que se muestran y ocultan completamente cuando se hace clic en cada elemento. Pero me gustaría ocultar cuando también se haga clic fuera de su área. Como veis estoy utilizando javascript vanilla.

El código html que utilicé para la estructura:

```
<header class="c-header">
  <div class="c-header__wrapper">
     <div class="c-header__row">
       <div class="c-header__menu-button js-menu-button"></div>
       <div class="c-header__search-button js-search-button"></div> 
     </div>

     <nav class="c-header__nav js-menu-expanded">
       <span class="c-header__nav-close js-menu-close">&times;</span>
       <ul class="c-header__nav-list">
         <li><a href="/" title="">Item</a></li>
       </ul>
     </nav>
                                           
     <div class="c-header__search js-search-expanded">
       <span class="c-header__search-close js-search-close">&times;</span>
       <form  action="">
         <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="...."> 
         <input type="submit" value="search">
       </form>
     </div>

   </div>
</header>
```

Tambien adjunto el css que he generado

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
.c-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}

.c-header__wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #25e5e5;
}

.c-header__row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: calc(100% - 17px);
  height: 58px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.c-header__menu-button, .c-header__search-button, .c-header__nav {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.c-header__menu-button, .c-header__search-button {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.c-header__search-button {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  background-color: orange;
}
.c-header__menu-button.is-active, .c-header__search-button.is-active {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: blue;
}
.c-header__nav {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 58px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
}
.c-header__nav.is-opened {
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.c-header__search {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 58px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
.c-header__search.is-opened {
  display: block;
}
```

El código js que tengo es este. Agregue un detector de eventos: `Node.contains()` para encontrar el objetivo del evento (que es el elemento más interno en el que se hace clic), pero cuando quiero borrar el class extra o añadiendo estilos en línea no acaba de funcionar.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var menu, toggleMenu, closeMenu, search, toggleSearch, closeSearch;
        
        // Set Elements
        menu = document.querySelector(".js-menu-expanded");
        toggleMenu = document.querySelector(".js-menu-button");
        closeMenu = document.querySelector(".js-menu-close");
        search = document.querySelector(".js-search-expanded");
        toggleSearch = document.querySelector(".js-search-button");
        closeSearch = document.querySelector(".js-search-close");

        // Toggle Menu
        toggleMenu.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            var isClickInside = toggleMenu.contains(event.target);
            if (isClickInside) {
                console.log('Click inside Open Nav'), 
                e.preventDefault();                 
                toggleMenu.classList.toggle('is-active');
                menu.classList.toggle('is-opened');
                menu.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                console.log('Click outside CLose Nav');
                toggleMenu.classList.remove('is-active');
                menu.classList.remove('is-opened');
                menu.style.display = "none";
            }
        })

        // Close Menu
        closeMenu.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.classList.remove('is-opened');
        });

        // Toggle Search
        toggleSearch.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            if (e.target !== toggleSearch) {
                console.log('Click inside Open Search'),  
                e.preventDefault();                 
                toggleSearch.classList.toggle('is-active');
                search.classList.toggle('is-opened');
                search.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                console.log('Click outside CLose Search');
                toggleSearch.classList.remove('is-active');
                search.classList.remove('is-opened');
                search.style.display = "none";
            }
        });


        // Close Search
        closeSearch.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            search.classList.remove('is-opened');
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Podés convertir tu código en un [repro], pulsando en el botón `<>` al editar tu pregunta.

Comment: Podés añadir CSS, hay muchas cosas con estilos propios, y el toggle lo estás haciendo sobre una clase, y sin el se ve poco y nada. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un par de errores:

1. Debes escuchar los clics en el documento, para analizar el elemento que lo recibió.
2. Estás recibiendo el evento como parámetro en la variable `e`, sin embargo, usas `event.target` en la primera línea de la función.

Además, también debes analizar si el clic se hizo en el menú:

```
// Toggle Menu
toggleMenu.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // Simplemente intercambias las clases
    toggleMenu.classList.toggle('is-active');
    menu.classList.toggle('is-opened');
});
// Escuchar clics en el documento para cerrar menú solo si está abierto
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // ¿El menú está abierto?, se puede saber si tiene la clase
    if(menu.classList.contains('is-opened')) {
        if(
            // El clic no fue en el menú
            e.target != menu
            // Ni en uno de sus hijos
            && !menu.contains(e.target)
            // Ni en el botón abrir / cerrar (ese ya escucha eventos)
            && e.target != toggleMenu
        ) {
            // Simplemente intercambias las clases
            toggleMenu.classList.toggle('is-active');
            menu.classList.toggle('is-opened');
        }
    }
});
```

Es importante que en CSS tengas las opciones para mostrar u ocultar el menú, por ejemplo:

```
/* Estado normal, oculto */
.js-menu-expanded {
    display: none;
}
/* Abierto */
.js-menu-expanded.is-opened {
    display: block;
}
```

Con esto evitas modificar los atributos CSS desde Javascript y, además, simplificas un poco la lógica, analizando solo la clase para saber si el menú está abierto o no.